# bash script switch user with exec

Tags: bash, docker, docker-entrypoint

I would like to run a docker entrypoint that creates a new user, switches to that user and destroys root shell so it cannot be exited back into

In the command line this works

```
$ useradd -s /bin/bash toby
$ exec su toby
```

If I exit from it the container stops which is as expected.

But, when I put this in a script the root shell is still there and can be exited into

--- NOTE ---
Sorry, I got things mixed up. 
This actually works as intended when I use the script as ENTRYPOINT

I didn't put username in the dockerfile as I want it be assigned on docker run as in

```
docker run -e USER=$USER myimage
```

Comment: `I put this in a script the root shell is still there and can be exited into` How do you execute the script?

Comment: why not simply using `USER toby` right before the end of the Dockerfile instead of `exec su toby`?

Comment: Add `ARG ${NEWUSER}` after `FROM image:tag` then do `RUN useradd -s /bin/bash ${NEWUSER} \ USER ${NEWUSER}` to switch to that user?

Comment: I wanted the username to be assigned on run